# What is this strange inversion?

Tags: grammar, word-order, inversion

> This case will show how widespread has been the reputation of this man.

In this sentence there is a subordinate clause:

> *how widespread has been **the reputation of this man***.

The subject of this clause is *the reputation of this man*. However, it comes  *after* the verb form *has been*. The subject and verb have been inverted.

What is this strange inversion. Is it correct?

Comment: *"This case will show [how widespread has been the reputation of this man]."* Yes, that does appear to be an interesting question. Like, what type is that subordinate clause? :)

Comment: @user8153 I've edited your question a bit so that people understand 'inversion'. If you want to change the formatting - or the edit - please do (and my name will not appear on your question any more).

Comment: @Araucaria did the OP actually look in lots of grammar books, or did you compose this? I'm abstaining on the reopen at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid word order, and it may be meant to place emphasis on certain parts of the sentence, particularly "the reputation of this man."

Answer (score 1):

> 1) *"This case will show [how widespread **has been** the reputation of this man]."*

It seems, at first blush, that the expression *"how widespread **has been** the reputation of this man"* in your example might be an **exclamative content clause**, which is functioning as the complement for the verb *"show"*.

The inversion that you noted seems to be due to the exclamative's subject getting **postposed** (with the resulting overall effect similar to **subject-dependent inversion**). The version without that inversion would be:

- 2) *"This case will show [ [how widespread] [the reputation of this man] **has been** ]."*

Notice that version #2 has the exclamative phrase (*"how widespread"*) **fronted**, which is what happens when it is not functioning as the subject. Aside: subject-auxiliary inversion does not usually occur for exclamative clauses when it is a main clause (and supposedly never if it is a subordinate clause) -- though it is available in main clauses it only occurs infrequently, or in literary style.

(Note that the word *"how"* is also used for interrogative clauses and fused relatives. The content clause in version #2 might be ambiguous as to its interpretation, as it could probably support both exclamative and interrogative interpretations.)

**RELATED INFO:**

The 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), page 921:

> ***Subject postposing***
>
> It is also possible for the subject to be postposed when the exclamative phrase is an adjectival predicative:
>
> - [11] *[How great] would have been [her disappointment] if she had known what they had actually thought!*

*CGEL* page 991:

> ***6 Exclamative content clauses***
>
> Subordinate exclamatives, like main clause exclamatives, are marked by one or the other of the exclamative words *what* and *how*:
>
> - [1.i] *He soon realized [what a terrible mistake he had made].*
> - [1.ii] *She told me [how very aggressive he had been].*
>
> One difference between subordinate and main exclamatives is that subject-auxiliary inversion is restricted to the latter, but since it applies there very rarely this is a minor difference -- quite unlike that holding between subordinate and main clause open interrogatives. As in main clauses, the subject may occur in postposed position: *They emphasized [ [how imperative] had been [the need to take immediate action] ].*