# Does a question always allow inversion of the subject and verb?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I referenced [♦](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/29161/8712) and [Why are the subject and the verb inverted after the conjunction 'as'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26817/8712), but they discuss only declarative statements (like my French question [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9100/lobjet-quest-le-soleil-pourquoi-pas-qui)).

Sadly, the technical linguistic terms in ♦ confuse me. It discusses (majuscules mine)

> the exclamative's subject getting postposed (with the resulting overall effect SIMILAR to subject-dependent inversion)
>   ...Notice that version #2 has the exclamative phrase ("how widespread") **fronted**

1. Does subject-verb inversion differ from "the subject to be postposed "? What's the latter called?
2. Where does **fronting** feature here? Is it  another separate concept (so the third one)?
3. Does a question always allow inversion of the subject and verb? Where might it not?

For example, I guess that the author inverts below, because it's easier to place the short verb ahead of the lengthy subject clause (that I've greyed)?

> Can the law hold that consulting
>   God for guidance is permissible but consulting any other non-corporeal entity is not allowed?
>   If so, what will the court say **is** `the validating element in religious faith in contradistinction to superstitious faith`?

[Source](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sIliAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA127&dq=%22How%20the%20Law%20Works%22%20Gary%20Slapper&pg=PA128#v=snippet&q=%22what%20will%20the%20court%22&f=false): p 160, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper, 2014.

Comment: By the way, *reference* is generally used as a verb when you are referring someone else to a source, not when you refer to the source yourself.

Comment: See [here](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/enc2010/articles/heavy-NP-shift.htm) about heavy-NP shift.

Comment: Echo questions don't permit inversion.

Answer (score 3):

The inversion in question (and in questions!) is not subject/verb inversion but subject/**auxiliary** inversion.

That is, these inversions require that the first component of the verb group be an auxiliary verb (but *BE* is always treated as an auxiliary). If no auxiliary is present in the declarative form, a form of *DO* is employed to provide the required auxiliary.

In your sentence the inversion has nothing to do with the verb *is*; that is the verb in the subordinate clause which is the object of the verb *say*:

> [<sub>SUBJ</sub>**The court**] [<sub>VERB GROUP</sub> [<sub>AUX</sub>**will**] [<sub>MAIN</sub>**say**]] *[<sub>OBJ.CLAUSE</sub>something] is the validating element ...*
>    ⇓
>    ⇓ *'something' is replaced with 'what', which is fronted;*
>    ⇓ *auxiliary 'will' and subject 'the court' are inverted;*
>    ⇓  *everything else remains in place.*
>    ⇓
>   *What* [<sub>AUX</sub>**will**] [<sub>SUBJ</sub>**the court**] [<sub>MAIN</sub>**say**] *is the validating element ...?*

This inversion is mandatory in questions.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the last sentence of this answer. You don't mean it is mandatory to invert an auxillary and subject in order to form a question?

Comment: @pazzo Yes. You can give interrogative intonation to echoic declarative sentences, and even incorporate interrogative pro-forms, in order to demand repetition or qualification of something previously put forward. But this is not what we ordinarily mean by "question".